# When retrieving a Stripe invoice from their API, how do I expand an object to retrieve credit card details and other info?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, stripe-payments

I have a Google Apps Script that accesses the Stripe API and retrieves data from a Stripe invoice [reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve) and adds the data to a Google Sheet.

Stripe mentioned that I can expand an object to get more info [expanding an object reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects). But I'm fairly new to using APIs so I'm not sure how to do this.

I think the reason I'm stuck is because I'm pulling the invoice data from a URL (i.e. https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx). I'm not sure how to modify the URL to expand an object (or where I should do this in the code below).

For example, I want to expand the "Charge" object to include more details about the payment. Data I'd want to get from the charge object would be the card type (ex: Visa), expiry, last four digits. I would likely do the same thing with the Customer object, to access customer details regarding the invoice.

Here's the Google Apps Script I'm using right now:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Stripe')
    .addItem('Retrieve Invoice Data','getInvoiceObj')
    .addToUi();
}

function getInvoiceObj() 
  {
    var apiKey, content, options, response, secret, url;

    //API Key
    secret = "rk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    //Stripe API invoice URL 
    url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


    options = {
      "method" : "GET",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + secret 
      },
      "muteHttpExceptions":true
    };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    //Push data to Sheet from invoice. **Writes over existing Sheet data**
    content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    //Retrieves currency type and adds to Sheet
    sheet.getRange(5,2).setValue([content.currency.toUpperCase()]);

    //Invoice amount due
    sheet.getRange(3,2).setValue([content.amount_due]);

    //Invoice date
    sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue([content.date]);

    //Invoice period begin
    sheet.getRange(6,2).setValue([content.lines.data[0].period.start]);

    //Invoice period end
    sheet.getRange(7,2).setValue([content.lines.data[0].period.end]);

    //Number of licenses
    sheet.getRange(10,2).setValue([content.lines.data[0].quantity]);

    //Invoice number
    sheet.getRange(13,2).setValue([content.number]);
```

Comment: So it looks like you'd need to use the charge value in the returned object to make another API call to Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve

Comment: I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question. So I would like to confirm about my understanding before post. Do you want to covert the sample curl command of [Expanding Objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) to Google Apps Script? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. When you fetch your invoice, the Stripe API returns an Invoice object [1](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object), which in turn has a `charge` field which contains the Charge ID. You could then make a separate call to `v1/charges/{charge_id_goes_here}` to get the charge details.
2. Expand the `charge` when fetching your invoice. I'm unfamiliar with `UrlFetchApp`, but you would have to specify in your request that you wish to expand the `charge` object. You'd send a GET request with the object you'd want to expand with type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Have a look how it's done in cURL, that might help you out: https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=curl

Separately, if you at all can I'd advise using the official [stripe-node](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) library, which will make interacting with the Stripe API much easier

Comment: Thanks Paul! That worked. In case anyone else wants to reference this in the future, to expand an object via URL you would use:  `https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/in_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?expand[]=charge`

Comment: Also, to expand multiple objects within the same API url, one can use `https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/in_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?expand[]=charge&expand[]=customer`